# Is it normal when BLEU score on filtered data by length is greater than BLEU score on whole data

Tags: nlp, machine-translation

I am creating 2 neural machine translation model (model A and B with different improvements each model) with fairseq-py. When I evaluate model with bleu score, model A BLEU score is 25.9 and model C is 25.7. Then i filtered data by length into 4 range values such as 1 to 10 words, 11 to 20 words, 21 to 30 words and 31 to 40 words. I re-evaluated on each filtered data and all bleu scores of model B is greater than model A. Do you think this is normal case?

Answer (score 1):

The original BLEU scores 25.9 and 25.7 are very close, there might not even be any significant difference. It's totally possible that model B performs better than model A on the filtered data only by chance. It's also possible that model B actually performs better than model A on shorter sentences. And finally it's worth noting that BLEU score is based on the number of n-grams in common, so it's likely to be affected by the length of sentences independently from the model being tested.

Conclusion: based on the information provided, this difference seems perfectly reasonable.